# Windows Live Movie Maker : Error 0xC00D0BC3

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-movie-maker

I have Win7Pro 64bits and everytime I try to publish a movie I get an error message :

> [Window Title] Windows Live Movie
>   Maker
>
> [Content] Sorry, your movie can't be
>   saved. Find any missing files or
>   remove the unusable items from your
>   project, and then try again.
>
> Error: 0xC00D0BC3
>
> [Close]

[image]

I have rebooted, reinstalled, try to repair, update all Windows update and still have this error.

What can I do to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt (type `cmd` into the Start menu search box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
2. Type `sfc /scannow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

That command scans all protected system files and replaces incorrect/corrupted versions with correct Microsoft versions.